# Highlighting a whole row if number of blank cells in the row = a certain number

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm trying to highlight a row if the number of blank cells between say, C1 and E1 = 3

and then copy this down for every row.

I've tried using:

```
=IF(COUNTBLANK($C1:$E1)=3)
```

But it's not working, can anybody help?

Comment: If this is CF just use `COUNTBLANK($C1:$E1)=3` - you need something which evaluates to TRUE or FALSE. And select the range first before applying, making sure row 1 is active.

Answer (score 0):

Under conditional formatting, your formula should be the following based on what you've given. The reason is conditional format is trying to see the result as TRUE or False. The IF statement is trying to tell the computer what to do when it's TRUE or FALSE.

`COUNTBLANK($C1:$E1)=3`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use `IF` you will need to do it like this:

```
=IF(COUNTBLANK($C1:$E1)=3, 1)
```